# What is the 'response time' of aws cloud trail and google appengine log?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam

I am searching for documentation or information regarding these two logging systems' 'response time'. I am sorry for the use of an imprecise term, but its meaning should be made clear in the following passage.

In aws, `Cloudtrail` can capture events related IAM changes and accesses and collect the logs into a S3 location.

In Google Cloud Platform I can also see permission related changes in one place.

However I am not able to find out the time aspect of these logging systems. I want to know what is the typical time between an audit event (IAM change/permission change/creation of new login etc etc) and its appearance in each logging system.

I am not looking for hard numbers. But if I can locate documentation that say, for example, 'Best effort', I will be delighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/faqs/):

> Q: How long does it take CloudTrail to deliver an event for an API call? 
>   Typically, CloudTrail delivers an event within 15 minutes of the API call.